# How to fill object with list using EF

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq, visual-studio-2012

How can I fill a list field using EF and linq of this model

```
public class Infraccion
{
    public int IdInfraccion { get; set; }
    public string Serie { get; set; }
    public int Numero { get; set; }
    public Direccion Direccion { get; set; }
    public string Comentario { get; set; }
    public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }
    public DateTime Hora { get; set; }
    public string Dominio { get; set; }
    public List<Contravencion> ListaDeContravenciones = new List<Contravencion>(); 
}
```

I DO know how to fill simple propertires, but dunno how to fill field List object where Contravencion is define like

```
public class Contravencion
{
    public string Articulo { get; set; }
    public string Inciso { get; set; }
    public int IdContravencion { get; set; }
    public string Descripcion { get; set; }
    public int UfijasMinimo { get; set; }
    public int UfijasMaximo { get; set; }
}
```

So far this is what I have

```
var listadoInfracciones = (from u in _context.Usuario
                           join ui in _context.UsuarioInfracciones on u.UsuarioId equals ui.UserId 
                           join i in _context.Infraccion on ui.InfraccionId equals i.InfraccionId
                           join d in _context.Direcciones on i.IdDireccion equals d.DireccionId
                           where ui.UserId == usuario.IdUsuario
                           select new Infraccion 
                           {
                               Comentario = i.Comentario,
                               Direccion = new Direccion
                               {
                                   Calle = d.Calle, 
                                   Entre1 = d.Interseccion1, 
                                   Entre2 = d.Interseccion2
                               }, 
                               Dominio = i.Dominio, 
                               Fecha = i.Fecha, 
                               Numero = i.Numero, 
                               Serie = i.Serie, 
                               ListaDeContravenciones = new List<Contravencion>()
                           }).ToList();
```

Where can't find the right way to fill the list of `Contravenciones`. Heres the DB model:

[image]

I've already seen these posts but do NOT fit my needs [Easy way to fill object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29243276/easy-way-to-fill-object)
[How to get data from the database into objectlists fast (with entity framework)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27848959/how-to-get-data-from-the-database-into-objectlists-fast-with-entity-framework)

Comment: Have you tried `ListaDeContravenciones  = i.ListaDeContravenciones`?

Comment: have you seen these http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30466696/query-a-many-to-many-relationship-with-linq-entity-framework-codefirst  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587288/many-to-many-query-in-entity-framework-4

Comment: I have now, but how do you get that list inside another list. I have to filter my "infracciones" table by user, and then get all "contravenciones" for each Infraccion. PS:Comment #1 did not solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i found a way to solve my problem. I'm pretty sure it's not the best way but i least have a result. If anyone can do this entirely with linq i certainly know would be helpful not just for me but for the entire comunity. Heres my code:

```
var listadoInfracciones = (from u in _context.Users
                       join ui in _context.User_Infraccion on u.UsuarioId equals ui.UserId 
                       join i in _context.Infraccions on ui.InfraccionId equals i.InfraccionId
                       join d in _context.Direccions on i.IdDireccion equals d.DireccionId
                       where ui.UserId == usuario.IdUsuario
                       select new Infraccion 
                       {
                           Comentario = i.Comentario,
                           Direccion = new Direccion
                           {
                               Calle = d.Calle, 
                               Entre1 = d.Interseccion1, 
                               Entre2 = d.Interseccion2
                           }, 
                           Dominio = i.Dominio, 
                           Fecha = i.Fecha, 
                           Numero = i.Numero, 
                           Serie = i.Serie,
                           IdInfraccion = i.InfraccionId
                       }).ToList();

        foreach (var inf in listadoInfracciones)
        {
            var test = (from contra in _context.Contravencions
                        where contra.Infraccion_Contravencion.Any(c => c.InfraccionId == inf.IdInfraccion)
                        select new Contravencion
                        {
                            Articulo = contra.Articulo,
                            Inciso = contra.Inciso,
                            UfijasMaximo = contra.UFijasMax,
                            UfijasMinimo = contra.UFijasMin,
                            Descripcion = contra.Descripcion,
                            IdContravencion = contra.ContravencionId
                        }).ToList();
            inf.ListaDeContravenciones = test;
        }
```

Cheers!